# ¿Como hacer animaciones o transiciones en JavaScript sin JQuery?

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo hacer animaciones en JavaScript puro? sin tener que usar librerias como JQuery.
Por ejemplo cambiar el color de fondo de un div igual que la propiedad transition de CSS3.

Ejemplo:

```
    div{

        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background: blue;
    }

    div:hover{

        background: red;

        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-property: background;
    }
```

¿Como puedo hacer una transición similar o animaciones en JavaScript puro?

Comment: Siempre que tengas el `HTMLElement` puedes acceder a su `classList` (para añadir y/o borrar clases de CSS) y a su `style` para [tocar directamente los estilos](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Una forma de emular ese comportamiento podría ser usando la función `setInterval()`, acceder a las propiedades del elemento, y cada determinado tiempo realizar una modificación.

En este caso he bajado la opacidad comenzando desde 0.99 hasta 0.50 y viceversa, además de cambiar el color cuando se cumplen ciertas condiciones.

Perdón si el código no ha quedado tan elegante.

Este ejemplo funciona al hacer click sobre el div.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("principal");
var valor = 100;
var intervalo;
var decremento = true;

//establecemos valores al div
div.style.width = "120px";
div.style.height = "120px";
div.style.background = "blue";
 
function detener(){
 clearInterval(intervalo);
 //restablecemos valores
 valor = 100;
 decremento = true;
}
  
div.addEventListener("click", function(){
 intervalo = setInterval(function(){
  if (decremento){
   valor--;
  }
  else {
   valor++;
  }
     
  //al dividir por 100 obtenemos los decimales que toma la funcion opacity
  div.style.opacity = valor / 100;
  
  if (valor == 50) {
   if (div.style.background == "blue"){
    div.style.background = "red";
   }
   else{
    div.style.background = "blue";
   }
   decremento = false;
  }
  
  else if (valor == 100 && !decremento){
   detener()
  }
  
 }, 30); 
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>transicion</title>

 
</head>
<body>
    Clikea en el cuadro para ver el resultado.
    <div id="principal">
 
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Hazme saber cualquier duda.

Saludos.