# Manejar transition con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero poder controlar una transition de CSS utilizando JavaScript.

Lo que quiero es mediante JavaScript poder ejecutar la transition hasta cierto punto, esto para que el "contenido" vaya ejecutando la transition según el scrool del usuario.
Tengo un código que luce más o menos así.

//HTML

```html
<div>
     <div class="contenido">
     </div>
</div/>
```

```css
div{

    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}

div .contenido{

    transition-property: width height; 
    transition-duration: .5s;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px; 
    margin: 20px 0;
}

div .contenido{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 70px 0;
}
```

```js
onScroll = ()=>{
    const body = document.body;
    const content = document.querySelector(".element")
    const scrollTop = body.scrollTop > 100? 100 : body.scrollTop; 

//El siguiente código es para dar un ejemplo
//Lógicamente no funciona.

    content.transitionMoment = `${scrollTop}%`;
    
}
```

Entonces quiero encontrar algo como un transitionMoment que me permita indicar el momento de la transition, así si un div debe cambiar el tamaño puedo establecer un momento en su cambio, por ejemplo 50% así si el div debe de moverse de un punto A a un punto B, poder mediante JavaScript establecerlo en la mitad de estos dos, 30% por ejemplo que lo establezca en el 30% de si transition a su posición final. Etc.

Se puede apreciar en las siguientes imágenes cómo el scroll de la barra de notificaciones a medida de que se realiza se van moviendo los iconos hasta pasar de seis iconos en su estado más compacto hasta solamente 4 en su estado desplegado.

..

**Aún no se empieza a realizar el scroll, podemos ver que en la parte superior hay seis iconos y no tienen ningún texto**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

...

**Se empieza a hacer el scroll y vemos como suavemente inicia la aparición del texto, desaparecen dos iconos y empiezan a crecer un poco los cuatro restantes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Ahora nos damos de cuenta que empiezan a verse más sus letras y a su vez empiezan a aparecer los demás iconos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Ahora vemos ya finalizó el scroll y junto a el su animacióm**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y cual es el problema o error que te sale???

Comment: puede que [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345882/como-hacer-animaciones-o-transiciones-en-javascript-sin-jquery) te ayude en tu problema

Comment: El problema es que cómo coloqué en el comentario en JS, trnasitionMoment no existe, y pretendo ejecutar la transición con javascript

Comment: Ya edité esta pregunta, espero haber logrado ser bastante claro y no haber dejado ninguna duda.

Comment: Mmmmm, ¿estás buscando algo similar a la API de [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: @padaleiana No, estoy buscando poder especificar el momento de la transition para que la transition no se ejecute por si sola, sino que esta se ejecute progresivamente a medida de que se vaya haciendo scroll

Comment: ¿Algo como un _scroll spy_? ¿Seguro que no necesitás lo que te mencionaba? [Acá](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-intersection-observer--cms-30250) hay varios ejemplos.

Comment: @padaleiana Ya miré lo que mandaste, pero lo que quiero hacer es, imagina un fondo azul el cual cambiará a color rojo a medida que se haga scroll y al volver el scroll este volverá a ser azul, ahora el color debe de cambiar progresivamente y lentamente mientras se hace el scroll.

Comment: Me da la sensación de que el ejemplo de la sección "Handling intersection changes" combinado el ejemplo de la sección "Thresholds" de MDN (el primer enlace que mencioné) es lo más cercano a lo que estás buscando. O al menos, eso es lo que dan a entender tus aclaraciones.

Comment: @padaleiana desarrollé un paquete en npm para lograr lo que buscaba. pudes echar un vistazo en https://npmjs.org/ayncat eso tal cual buscaba, solo que buscaba alguna api del navegador que me permitiera hacerlo sin escribir los estilos en css.